# In CQRS how to work with NServiceBus to update Command and Query store

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc-5, cqrs, nservicebus5

In CQRS, how do you make sure a command handler is updating the write store and read store transactionally?

I am not sure if these two steps are suppoed to be a transaction?
Or do you rely on eventual consistency here? Meaning the read store will be updated eventually?

**What is the (or a) common way to do this using NServiceBus 5 or 6?**

In our application, we have `IRepository<T>` (Add, Update) for the command side to update Sql Server database.
The query side is simple. A database and a facade on top of Entity Framework `DbContext`.

The steps on the command side would be:

1. MVC controller receives data from View
2. controller action creates a Command/Message object and sends it to the bus.
3. The proper command handler creates the appropriate domain object and does validation on it.
4. If valid, uses IRepository to insert or update the database.
5. Now what?

Does this have to be a Saga in NServiceBus, where Step 1 and 2 update the command store and read store?

Thank you.

Comment: +1, how did you approach this in the end? Do you create two messages (one for write and one for read) or do you execute the write insert and then create a message for the read? Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

The flow I see is the following:

- the controller receives an action and emits a command in the command bus
- the proper command handler gets fired and the write models get updated
- in the command handler, an event is fired
- the proper event handler gets fired and the read models get updated

So updating the read models get done in an event handler - hence the eventual consistency

Hope this helps! Best of luck!

Comment: but what if something goes wrong, e.g. the read store cannot be updated, or the command store cannot be updated. Shouldn't both operations be within some sort of transaction? Thanks for your help.

Comment: That's why it's called eventual consistency. If something goes wrong in the event handler that updated the read data, you can always just flag that it went wrong and retry the execution.  (Since you have very granular event handlers, you won't have to do a thing 2 times)

Comment: Ok. So "flag" means I would raise another event (e.g. SyncFailedEvent) that would be handled in the MVC app, e.g. to notify the user of the error? And this also goes through the NServiceBus?

Comment: I'm not sure that the end user needs to know that the read model hasn't been successfully updated, but you can either raise an event that it failed, or catch it in a try-catch block.

Comment: +1, how did you approach this in the end? Do you create two messages (one for write and one for read) or do you execute the write insert and then create a message for the read? Thanks.